# GAE Managed VMs - can't deploy if your project name is too long

Tags: google-app-engine, docker, gcloud

Currently the GAE Managed VMs feature is broken for any project with a name longer than 27 characters.

The underlying issue is that Docker restricts image namespace to between 4-30 chars. This has been fixed (https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/10392) but is still awaiting a release at time of writing.

It seems when deploying a Managed VM to GAE that the namespace is automatically generated from your project name plus `_m_` prefix. This leads to error when attempting to deploy the vm:

```
DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/images/gcr.io/_m_<my project name>/<my project name>.default.20150330t140211/push HTTP/1.1" 500 111
INFO: Exception 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("Invalid namespace name (_m_<my project name>). Cannot be fewer than 4 or more than 30 characters.") thrown in ProgressHandler. Retrying.
```

The obvious solution would be for GAE `gcloud` tools to respect the underlying limit via some auto-truncation or hashing scheme.

Does anyone know a way around this? Or I have to wait for Google to fix or Docker to release a new version and Google to update?

Answer (score 3):

We're aware of the issue and we're working on a long-term fix. For now, you can switch to an old version of gcloud. You can do this by setting this variable to point to an old version (0.9.51):
gcloud config set --scope=installation component_manager/fixed_sdk_version 0.9.51

then run "gcloud components update"

Then run "gcloud config set app/hosted_registry false"

and you should be able to deploy. I'll update this answer when we've fixed the naming issue.

UPDATE:
The naming issue has been fixed as of this week's release (0.9.57).

Comment: I followed above but get the following error when I try to deploy: `Failed to connect to Docker Daemon due to: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]` ...this is familiar, I tried [the fix here](https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/890#issuecomment-84468058) (i.e. disable TLS in docker daemon) but I get a new error `Failed to connect to Docker Daemon due to: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER]`

Comment: do I have to downgrade my local system docker/boot2docker install as well?

Comment: I saw @dlorenc's note and upgraded to the new version. I was able to deploy, but my deploy was seriously borked (503s, no logs in the GAE admin console, something is screwy). So I waited a few hours, came home, and now can't deploy anymore. Updating module [default].../DEBUG: "GET /v1/_ping HTTP/1.1" 200 None
Updating module [default].../DEBUG: "POST /v1.10/images/gcr.io/_m_sdk/shiftdpxdt.default.10/push HTTP/1.1" 500 86
INFO: Exception 500 Server Error: Internal Server Error ("v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get http://gcr.io/v1/_ping: dial tcp: i/o timeout") thrown in ProgressHandler.